# What is self in __init__ method of a class in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, class, oop

HI i have a doubt regarding the argument passed is `__init__` method in class of python. People will say this is class instance is being passed here as as first argument in the `__init__` method.

```
Class A():

   def __init__(self):
       pass

   def check(self):
      pass

a = A()
a.check()
```

as we understood that here 'a' is being passed as in first argument in the method `__init__`. But here we have just created the instance of class A. As for other method check , when we will do `a.check()`, will understand OK here we are calling check with a instance of class so it is being passed. but for `__init__` method , we didn't do anything ,just created the instance. so then how it is being passed.

for an example, 
a = a + 10...this will not work untill and unless we will initialize a in starting for this expression. so same with `__init__`.

we have just created instance here as a = A(). then a will be passed here.

i know my question is bit tricky. But this has been asked to me in an interview.

Please can someone help here ?

Comment: Except when the `__new__` is overridden (or a meta-class is used) that disables this behavior. The `__init__` is **always** called when constructing an object. It acts like a *constructor* (like for instance in Java).

Comment: hi @WillemVanOnsem.. Thanks for your answer, i am aware of the fact that this is constructor same as java. But my question bit different. like to understand how self is being passed here as an first argument , if we didn't call this method with this argument.

Answer (score 6):

Not `a` will be passed, **the class instance** is passed. The instance exists before it is assigned to `a`. It exists independently of `a`. Take for instance:

```
[A() for _ in range(5)]
```

There will be 5 instances of `A` created, even though they're not directly assigned to any variable (the list expression may be assigned, but each individual `A()` is not).

When instantiating a class, `__new__` of that class creates the new instance, then calls `__init__` on it, then the new instance is returned and (in your case) assigned to `a` (for more in-depth details see https://stackoverflow.com/a/43187010/476).

Comment: I was going to mention `__new__` as well, it goes a long way in helping understand how `__init__` really works.  Good job

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. @deceze. Make sense.

Answer (score 5):

The order of steps (assuming the standard metaclass `type`) in this example is

1. `A()` is implemented using `type.__call__(A)`.
2. `type.__call__(A)` calls `A.__new__`.
3. `A.__new__` resolves to `object.__new__`, which returns a new instance of `A`.
4. `type.__call__(A)` passes the return value of `object.__new__` to `A.__init__` (where `self` is the name used for this first argument to `__init__`).
5. `type.__call__(A)` then returns the (initialized) object, which is bound to the name `a`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations .